# Google Maps v3 - zoom in/zoom out able to repeat (and recenter)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I have a Google map with multiple POLYGON areas.  I have figured out how to ZOOM IN with a single click on the polygon, and ZOOM OUT with a 'dblclick' listener and remove the listeners for them...

Once you have clicked to Zoom In, then double clicked to Zoom Out, it's not allowing me to repeat the function again.  Is there a way to zoom in and out multiple times?

Here is the code I have:

```
     //POLYGON ZONE 1 ================================ 
  var zone1;

  var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(29.738692, -95.399331),
    new google.maps.LatLng(29.738688, -95.394781),
    new google.maps.LatLng(29.737048, -95.394781),
    new google.maps.LatLng(29.737048, -95.399331)
  ];

  // Construct the polygon
  // Note that we don't specify an array or arrays, but instead just
  // a simple array of LatLngs in the paths property
  zone1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: "#00AEEF",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#00AEEF",
    fillOpacity: 0.05,
  });

  zone1.setMap(map);
  zone1._myBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i=0; i<triangleCoords.length; i++)
  {
     zone1._myBounds.extend(triangleCoords[i]);
  }

  var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(zone1, 'click', function () {
      map.fitBounds(zone1._myBounds);
      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener); 
  });

    var listener2 = google.maps.event.addListener(zone1, 'dblclick', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() > 16) map.setZoom(13); 
    //map.setZoom(map.getZoom() -1);
    //map.setCenter(map.getCenter());
    google.maps.event.removeListener(listener2); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(zone1, 'click', function (){
        map.fitBounds(zone1._myBounds);});
  });
```

For my other POLYGON areas, would I also have to change the variable names for them to work?

Also, the return to center doesn't seem to be working properly. If I need to ask that in a separate question I will.

Comment: Why are you removing the listeners if you want to do it again?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you don't do the same thing in the click listener you add on dblclick:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(zone1, 'click', function (){
    map.fitBounds(zone1._myBounds);});
```

vs the original:

```
var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(zone1, 'click', function () {
  map.fitBounds(zone1._myBounds);
  google.maps.event.removeListener(listener); 
});
```

Comment: so by using this code for polygon1, it won't effect polygon2? :
`google.maps.event.addListener(zone1, 'click', function (){
    map.fitBounds(zone1._myBounds);});

google.maps.event.addListener(zone1, 'dblclick', function (){
    if (map.getZoom() > 16) map.setZoom(13);});`